# How to setVisibility for control in TabActivity from Activity (tab)?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

My `TabActivity` contains `ProgressBar` and two tabs (`Activities` with `ListView`).

Where does I must initialize `progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bc);` and how can I set `progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);` from `onItemClick` in `ListView` in `Activity`?

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progress_bc"
    android:indeterminate="true" 
    android:layout_width="18dip" 
    android:layout_height="18dip"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization should be to the `Activity` where you want to show the dialog. So it is better to have two `ProgressBar`, one for every layout of your two `Activities` and control it there.

So in the tab parent Activity (call it CustomTabActivity):

```
public ProgressDialog dialog;
```

In the `onCreate()` you initialize the dialog.

Now when you want to use it from a child Activity, you use:

`((CustomTabActivity)getParent()).dialog.show();` or

```
((CustomTabActivity)getParent()).dialog.dismiss();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know how to do this, but I hope there is a way to use **one** `progressBar` in `TabActivity` because I don't have good place in Activities for `.ProgressBar.Small` but I have this under the Tabs in `TabActivity` :)

Comment: Then you should access it via the getParent() method where you can access objects of your parent activity, which in this case is the TabActivity.

Comment: as you deleted my changes, can you edit answer or create new with explanations how to use `getParent()` rightly in my question? And I'll choose it as an answer on the question :)